# Sorting based on boolean flag remove default alphabetical sorting

Tags: c#

I have a requirement where I have list this list is getting populated from the SQL Database, the list has a boolean field now the list has to be sorted based on this field.But it should not do the default sorting within the sorted result.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<NP> np=new List<NP>()
        {
            new NP()
            {
                IsSelected = true,
                Desc="DN"
            },
            new NP()
            {
                IsSelected = false,
                Desc="JL"
            },
            new NP()
            {
                IsSelected = true,
                Desc="ON"
            },
            new NP()
            {
                IsSelected = true,
                Desc="PR"
            },
            new NP()
            {
                IsSelected = false,
                Desc="PS"
            },
            new NP()
            {
                IsSelected = true,
                Desc="RPA"
            },
        };
        List<NP> orNP = np.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSelected).ToList();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class NP
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

But i want to show in this order:
* ON
* RPA
* PR
* DN
* PS
* JL

Comment: Create a list of order : List<string> sortOrder = new List<string>() {"ON", "RPA", "PR", "DN", "PS", "JL"}; Then sort on the index of item np.OrderByDescending(x => sortOrder.IndexOf(x.Desc));

Comment: Your result is not matching the order of the elements in the list. Just look at the elements in your list with IsSelected set to true. The order of those elements in your result does not match the order (or reverse order) of those elements in the list. This is called unstable sorting. If you need an unstable sorting algorithm that produces a specific, particular unstable sorting order, you would need to program it by hand, i guess..

Comment: What's significant about that specific order? If you want that kind of sort order, you should store an ordinal mapping, and sort by that, eg. `OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSelected).ThenBy(x => x.SortOrder)`

Comment: Thanks Willaien thats what i thought, i dont see other way to achieve this, the business want in this specific order